# THREEjs, updating an object's matrix doesnt change it's position and rotation params

Tags: matrix, three.js, transformation

I want to set a transformation matrix to an object upon creation and then control it by position, rotation and scale, but while changing the matrix does change the object in world space, it's position parameter still remains 0, 0, 0.

```
let mesh =  new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0xf15728})
)
this.scene.add(mesh)

let pos = new THREE.Vector3().setFromMatrixPosition(m)

mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false
mesh.matrix.copy(m)

// ***************//
mesh.updateMatrix()
// ***************//

console.log("mesh.position", mesh.position)
console.log("pos", pos)
```

Here's the output for the values of both `pos` and `mesh.position`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Updating an objects `matrix` does not update its position or rotation fields and by default three.js will update the matrix based on the `position`, `rotation`, and `scale` values before rendering (which you've disabled by setting `matrixAutoUpdate` to false).

If you would like to initialize an objects transformation from a matrix you can use the [Matrix4.decompose](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Matrix4.decompose) function like so:

```
// m is the initial local matrix transform
m.decompose(
  mesh.position,
  mesh.quaternion,
  mesh.scale,
);
```

Also if you keep `mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false` you will have to call `mesh.updateMatrix()` before rendering whenever the `position`, `rotation`, or `scale` values are changed.

You can read more on how matrix transformations work [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Matrix-transformations).